# PHP - Load a information depending on the domain

Tags: php

I was wondering if I could point any amount of domains to certain directory, and depending on the URL, it will show some information of the database. also, this database is shared with another domain.

what would be the best way to achieve this?

I was thinking to use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and according to that, I could have a template that would load the information according to the name of the domain.

Comment: This question is to generic. It depends to much on the concrete environment, your requirements and goals to suggest a best way. For a small and simple setup your suggested solution seems well enough for me.

Comment: could there be a way to try this without buying a domain and test it?

Comment: Sure, you can setup a local webserver on your computer. If you are on windows you can try Xamp or something similar. Than you need to edit your hosts file. This way you can bind a local directory with your code to a fantasy domain name like test.local.com